# GIT merge branch code with latest hotfix code

Tags: git

I have created a separate branch in git for my new requirement and i have pushed/commited my changes in that new branch.

Finally, i have to merge my branch with the latest hotfix branch.

Am not sure how i can do that using `git bash commands`.

for example :

```
My new branch : Requirement1_branch
hotfix branch : hotfix
```

Still now, am doing the manual comparasion of files and doing the merge. Is there any other way to do merge using git bash.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout Requirement1_branch
git merge hotfix
```

refs:

[git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt)

[git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_description)